# Multiple grep piping (include+exclude) results in not showing anything

Tags: linux, grep

Currently I'm trying to `tail` a log but only showing the lines that has some keywords. Currently I'm using

```
tail -F file.log | grep -ie 'error\|fatal\|exception\|shutdown\|started'
```

and I'm getting the expected results: (for example)

```
10:22 This is an error
10:23 RuntimeException: uncaught problem
```

I also want to exclude lines that contain a `<DATATAG>`, even if the keywords slipped into it, because it contains a lot of binary data that clutters my log. I'm then trying to add to the pipe another grep that excludes the tag:

```
tail -F file.log | grep -ie 'error\|fatal\|exception\|shutdown\|started' | grep -vF '<DATATAG>'
```

However, this time no lines appear, not even the previous ones that has 'error'/'exception' but not `<DATATAG>`. When I tried the excluding grep alone:

```
tail -F file.log | grep -vF '<DATATAG>'
```

all lines appear, including those that have 'error'/'exception'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's buffering as @jzer7 says but instead of multiple greps and pipes, consider just one awk: `tail -F file.log | awk '!/<DATATAG>/ && tolower($0)~/error|fatal|exception|shutdown|started/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of buffering.  `grep` is a tricky tool when it comes to that.  From the man page:

```
By default, output is line buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered otherwise.
```

In your example, the first `grep` is buffering at the block level, so it will not turn an output to the 2nd `grep` for a while.  The solution is to use the `--line-buffered` option to look like:

```
tail -F file.log | grep --line-buffered -ie 'error\|fatal\|exception\|shutdown\|started' | grep -vF '<DATATAG>'
```